# Move an object into a corner of the screen

Tags: javascript, html

I recently started (trying) to code a basic stop/start audio toggle for my website which would sit in the bottom right hand corner of my website. I was hoping I could get it to sit next to a "scroll to top" button I already have on my website but couldn't work out how to get it to go there.

[Image of where the new button should sit.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkVF8.jpg)

I have no idea what to do as I am completely hopeless at all this coding stuff. Heres what I got so far:

```
<html>
<img src=http://www.thegeekypixel.com/files/theme/Images/play.png  onclick="javascript:toggleSound();">

<audio id="audio" autoplay loop>
<source src="http://www.thegeekypixel.com/uploads/1/9/7/1/19711247/once_again_-_tristam.mp3">
</audio>

<script type="text/javascript">
function toggleSound() {
  var audioElem = document.getElementById('audio');
  if (audioElem.paused)
    audioElem.play();
  else
     audioElem.pause();
    }
</script>

<style>
img:hover {
    opacity: 0.5;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
    </style>
    </html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5ennwx7p/

So my question is this, how do I get the HTML image/object to sit in the bottom left hand corner of the window (like the scroll to top element shown in the image above)?

Thanks,
Oliver

Also, sorry for any posting in the wrong section or for any errors, I don't know what I'm doing when it comes to code.

Also, I plan to change the image and the assets when I'm finished, they're just temporary.

Comment: Delete the question or leave it anyway for further reference. Btw you got up voted for this question

Answer (score 2):

just add the css

```
position: fixed; bottom:0; right:0;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5ennwx7p/1/

Answer (score 0):

You should add the css `position: fixed; bottom: 0; right: 0` on the element to get the it in the bottom right of the screen. `right: 0` is the distance the element is from the right of the parent object, which is the screen in this instance because we're give it a fixed position. In order to get it next to the other element, and not ontop of it, he would have to add some amount to the right, like `right: 20px`

Also, you could add an ID to easily select the element in the css.

```
<img id="radioButton" src=.../play.png  onclick="javascript:toggleSound();">

<style>
    #radioButton {
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;
        right: 20px;
    }
    #radioButton:hover {
        opacity: 0.5;
        filter: alpha(opacity=50);
    }
</style>
```